# How to compute accuracy of a multilabel classifier in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, multilabel-classification

I am trying to build a multilabel model in Tensorflow. A section of my code is below. I think that the accuracy should be computed differently, not like for binary and multiclass models. Should this remain the same? If not, what is the right way to compute accuracy for a multilabel problem?

```
cost = -tf.reduce_sum( (  (y*tf.log(pred + 1e-9)) + ((1-y) * tf.log(1 - pred + 1e-9)) )  , name='xentropy' )

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
```

Also, what is the best way to evaluate the performance of the multilabel model (preferred metric is AUROC). Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean multi-label (where each item can have different labels) or multi-class(as opposed to binary)?

Comment: Multi-label (where each item can have more than one label) e.g. [0,1,0,1,1], [0,1,1,0,0]